# In a relative layout, how to place a textview below an imagebutton and align it to the center of the imagebutton?

Tags: android-layout

In a relative layout, I have a large imagebutton and I have to place a textview below-center the imagebutton. In the textview declaration i used `android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Button1`. But because the button is bigger than the textview, it layouts as follows:

```
______Imagebutton______

Textview_______________
```

I wanted the layout to be:

```
____ImageButton____

_____TextView______
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the `ImageButton` does not fill the width of the `RelativeLayout`, the easiest way might be to add the following to the `TextView`:

```
android:layout_below="@id/Button1"
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/Button1"
android:layout_alignRight="@id/Button1"
android:gravity="center"
```

This will make the text view the same width as the `ImageButton` with centered text (which may or may not fit your needs).

If the `ImageButton` occupies the entire width of the `RelativeLayout`, it is an easier case -- you can simply add the following to the `TextView`:

```
android:layout_below="@id/Button1"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Comment: thanks...I tried the first option...this made the textview the same width as the imagebutton, but I would prefer if the textview retained its width and jus centered below the imagebutton......but thankyou anyway!!!

Comment: removed alignRight and added 
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" to get it centered

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to place anything in center of `RelativeLayout` then, You can use these attributes**

Give id to and `ImageButton`, eg. `@+id/img_btn`

Now in `TextView`, add this attribute:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/img_btn"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```